# How To share the extended Custom SQL Code Analysis Rule dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have build and extended the Static SQL Code Analysis Rules of SSDT projects. Its working perfectly in my local system by copying the class library DLL into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Extensions" location.

Now, My challenge is to share this dll to others developer. How this can be easily shared ?. I don't want this one to be copied manually to the DAC extension folder by everyone.

It should be like a nuget package or an extension upon downloading of that should be installed in the user DAC extension folder.

Can anyone help me here ? How this can be achieved ?

I tried to create an VSIX Extension project and tried to install the custom rule dll into the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Extensions" directory. But i failed to do so.

Post build event : copy "$(TargetDir)\TSqlRules$(TargetExt)" "$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Extensions\TSqlRules$(TargetExt)" /y

Custom Rule DLL should be installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Extensions" directory.

Answer (score 0):

> It should be like a nuget package or an extension upon downloading of
>   that should be installed in the user DAC extension folder.

Not sure about the best way to do this. But for your simple requirement, `nuget package` is more convenient than the `vs extension` if all you want is to share a single dll to specified location.

You can include [Init.ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892025/nuget-install-ps1-does-not-get-called) file and your `xxx.dll` when you create your package. And type the copy command into Init.ps1 (similar to what you do in post-build-event).When your nuget package is consumed by any project in **VS IDE**, it will call the power shell script `Init.ps1`. Then the ps script can work to copy the `xxx.dll` from packages folder to destination location.

Related link: [Run power shell script during nuget package installation and removal](https://everydaylifein.net/netframework/running-powershell-scripts-during-nuget-package-installation-and-removal.html).